# upload image to Google App Engine and share the image with the users

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, blobstore

Are there examples to upload an image to Google App Engine(Python) through HTTP? Also, is it possible to retrieve the image from Blob store and share the image link to someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [an example of a guestbook app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages) from Google, where users can upload avatar images.  It explains how to use the `db.BlobProperty()` to store the image.  How to write a handler to upload (`class Guestbook`), and how to serve the image (`class Image`).  It even goes on to explain how to scale images.

Answer (score 2):

Use [create_upload_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions) to create a URL the you can use to upload your images direct to the blobstore/cloud storage.

From there you can either use [get_seving_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions) to create a URL to your image that can be shared with users to access your image, or if you want access control over who can access the image then use send_blob and BlobstoreDownloadHandler to send your images back to your users.